# Jupyter Notebook - EnvironmentError:

Tags: python

When I type:

> pip install webdriver_manager

I'm getting this>>>

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\backports\\__init__.py' Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try running Jupyter notebook as an administrator.

To do that, type cmd in your windows search bar, right-click the option, and select "run as administrator". Then type jupyter notebook into the command prompt, and it will run as an administrator

Comment: When I type jupyter notebook, I get this error - C:\WINDOWS\system32>jupyter notebook 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Then how do you usually access your jupyter notebook?

Comment: Via Anaconda prompt

Comment: well run anaconda as administrator then and click on jupyter notebook

Comment: I did the command in Anaconda prompt (run as Administator) and it worked.  I'll run the codes and see if I still get the original error. Thnx

Comment: I entered this >>>link = all_urls[i]
    browser.get(link)
    src = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml') and received this error>>>>NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-cd0bddae9750> in <module>
     39 
     40     link = all_urls[i]
---> 41     browser.get(link)
     42     src = browser.page_source
     43     soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

NameError: name 'browser' is not defined

Comment: well you'd probably have to define browser first. But the original error dissapeared?

Comment: Yes, the original error disappeared.  I defined the browser as Google Chrome

Comment: Could you please accept my answer then, if it solved your error?

Comment: Thanks! (comments must be 15 characters)